# NFA to DFA conversion for the language (111+11111)*

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa, nfa

[image: NFA For language (111+11111)*]

I have constructed the NFA for the language (111+11111)*. After that i am trying to convert it into DFA but i am stuck. Please anybody can provide the step by step Conversion of the given NFA to DFA.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct NFA for this language? As far as I know for the input 11111111 the automaton can go the following path:
A->B->C->A->B->C->A->B->C and C is not a final state.

Comment: Yes the NFA is correct for 11111111 the path follows : 
A-B-C-A-B-C-D-E-A and A is the final state

Comment: @Rashin the NFA is correct for the string 11111111 the path follows : 
A B C A B C D E A and A is the final state so accepted

Comment: For the same input the path can be different. One path (which is good) is what you show, other path is provided by me which is not accepted this automaton but valid.

Comment: @Rashin that is why it is called Non Deterministic because there are multiple paths for the same input otherwise it will be Deterministic. But I still did not got my answer that is conversion

Comment: The algorithm for converting from an NFA to a DFA involves building sets that are all reachable from the current set of nodes. So you'll end up with states and transitions `{A} -> {B} -> {C} -> {A, D} -> {B, E} -> {A, C} -> {A, B, D} -> etc`. Any state whose set contains `A` is accepting.

Comment: @Welbog I know the algorithm but the states I derived while conversion keep on generating new states and I was unable to end and that's why I need the help. I want the step by step answer not the hints to solve the problem . I know the process but I am not able to find the solution.

Comment: Then please share the steps you have tried and where you feel that things are breaking down. Stack Overflow exists to answer specific questions about specific problems. The algorithm must end due to the simple fact that there are only finitely many subsets of `{A, B, C, D, E}`. In fact, there are 32 such subsets, so your DFA can have at most 32 states, and there will be at most 32 iterations of the NFA to DFA algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a NFA to a DFA, you can use **Subset Construction** method.
You need to enumerate all possible combinations of your states in NFA as new states( 2^|Q| new states) and write their transitions.

1. generate transition tables

first column means the new states. Second row means the state in first row which take an input 1, which states it can go. For example, when state {A} get an input 1, it will go to state {B}; when state {A,D} get an input 1, it will go to {B,E} because t(A,1)=B and t(D,1)=E.

[image]

2. Rename the new states

Give a new state name for the first row in the table

3. Remove the unreachable states

Since we already have the transition table, I think you can easily build a DFA based on that.

Answer (score 0):

To convert NFA to DFA we use subset construction method,

from the given NFA, the transitions are:

```
δ(A,1)={B}
δ(B,1)={C}
δ(C,1)={D,A}
δ(D,1)={E}
δ(E,1)={A}
```

We obtained a new state {D,A}
transitions of the new state are:

```
δ({D,A},1)=δ(D,1) U δ(A,1)
          ={B,E}
```

We again obtained a new state {B,E}
transitions of the new state are:

```
δ({B,E},1)=δ(B,1) U δ(E,1)
          ={C,A}
```

We obtained a new state {C,A}
transitions of the new state are:

```
δ({C,A},1)=δ(C,1) U δ(A,1)
          ={D,A,B}
```

Now We obtained a new state {D,A,B}
transitions of the new state are:

```
δ({D,A,B},1)=δ(D,1) U δ(A,1) U δ(B,1)
            ={E,B,C}
```

We obtained a new state {E,B,C}
transitions of the new state are:

```
δ({E,B,C},1)=δ(E,1) U δ(B,1) U δ(C,1)
            ={A,C,D}
```

We obtained a new state {A,C,D}
transitions of the new state are:

```
δ({A,C,D},1)=δ(A,1) U δ(C,1) U δ(D,1)
            ={B,D,A,E}
```

We further obtain new states {C,E,B,A},{D,A,C,B},{A,B,C,D,E}.

So, there are 10 new states obtained.
The transitions of the new states are:

```
δ({D,A},1)={B,E}          δ({A,C,D},1)={B,D,A,E} 
δ({B,E}1)={C,A}           δ({B,D,A,E}1)={C,E,B,A}
δ({C,A},1)={D,A,B}        δ({C,E,B,A}1)={D,A,C,B}
δ({D,A,B},1)={B,C,E}      δ({D,A,C,B}1)={E,B,D,A,C}
δ({E,B,C},1)={A,C,D}      δ({E,B,D,A,C}1)={A,C,E,B,D}
                                         ={E,B,D,A,C}
```

DFA is:

[Refer the below image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMC6v.jpg